# Overflow value being ignored when using percentage height hack

Tags: css

Given the following CSS declarations used to create a responsive grid of squares:

```
nav a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  width: 25%;
}

nav a p {
  display: none;
}

nav a:hover p {
  display: block;
}
```

`overflow: hidden` is not being respected when the child element is displayed. The child appears to extend the height of the parent and pushes the element below its parent out of place.

I'm pretty sure this is a result of using the padding-bottom/percentage hack I'm using to achieve flexible squares, as everything works as expected when using fixed heights.

Is there a workaround? Is there a different technique I should be using?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2qaz1dLx/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that the padding-bottom is causing the fifth element out of place. When you hover over your `<a>`, the height of the element is increased by the height of the revealed `<p>` and then an additional 25% padding-bottom is added on top of that hence causing your element below to be shifted right.

To avoid this, we can absolutely position your revealed `<p>` so that its height is not calculated when adding the padding-bottom.

https://jsfiddle.net/2qaz1dLx/2/

As for whether this is a good idea...probably not, flexbox is pretty well supported in modern browsers nowadays

Comment: Thanks, that summation of the problem makes perfect sense. I will probably attempt the absolutely positioned approach, as I think it might be _a good enough idea_ for my use case. Also, afaik, flexbox doesn't lend itself well to controlling the number of columns in a grid, which is something I'll need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: absolute` to the `nav a p` class

```
nav a p {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```css
nav {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  width: 25%;
}

nav a p {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

nav a:hover p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a>
    one
    <p>one child</p>
  </a>
  <a>
    two
    <p>two child</p>
  </a>
  <a>
    three
    <p>three child</p>
  </a>
  <a>
    four
    <p>four child</p>
  </a>
  <a>
    five
    <p>five child</p>
  </a>
</nav>
```